# issue when copying hive partitioned table from one cluster to another

Tags: hive, distcp

I run a distcp command to copy the hdfs location of a table to another cluster.
The copy is scheduled to run every 8 hours.
I run the 'msck repair table' command but not always after the copy.
I have noticed that sometimes some partitions of the table have suffixes like '.tmp~!@ ' although the copy was successful.
What can cause this issue?
I even see sometimes some partitions that does not exist in the original table.
Appreciate any help!

Thank you!